# SQL: What is appropriate query for this?

Tags: sql

**Q. List the names of the products that were not featured in a deal in last trailing 12 months.**

Deals Table

```
i.  Deal_id 
ii. Product_id
iii.    Deal_start_date
iv. Deal_end_date
```

Product Dim Table

```
i.  Product_id
ii. Product_name
iii.    Manufacturer
```

---

My answer is:

```
Select Product_name, Rank() over(partition by year(Deal_start_date) order by Deal_start_date desc) as Deal_date
 From Product Dim Table
 Right join Deals Table on Product Dim Table.Product_id=Deals Table.Product_id
 where Deal_date > 1
 Group by Product_name
 Order by Deal_date desc
```

Comment: I've removed the incompatible database products - please retag with the DBMS you're actually using.

Comment: `Select * from product P where not exists (Select "1" from Deals D where D.Product_Id = P.Product_ID and D.Deal_End_Date>="today-12 months"` where today-12 months is specific to RDBMS used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Select p.Product_name
From Product p
Where not exists
    (Select * from Deals
     where Product_id = p.Product_id
         and Deal_start_date <= @today
         and Deal_end_date >= start)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the followinf. /
    select 
    Product_id, Product_name, Manufacturer
    from product dim
    where
    product_id not in (
    select product_id
    from 
    Deals
    where
    deal_end_date between 
        Deal_end_dare>DateAdd(mm,-12, GetDate())

)